# 2-Wasserstein (optimal transport) and extension to the set of all signed measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, optimal-transportation

Consider the 2-Wasserstein distance between probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ (on $\mathbb{R}^d$), defined as 
$$
 d_{W_2}(\mu,\nu) = \inf_{\gamma} \Big[\int \|x-y\|^2 d\gamma(x,y)\Big]^{1/2}
$$
where the $\inf$ is over all couplings $\gamma$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$. Can we define a norm (or something norm-like) on the space of signed measures (or a linear subspace of it containing the cone of probability measures) which gives rise to $W_2$ for probability measures. (I suppose not, but why?)

If not, can we approximate $d_{W_2}$ by a norm?

Comment: There is a dual formulation of Wasserstein distance which makes perfect sense for signed measures, although I don't know what pathological behaviors it might have in that generality.  For comparison, this paper discusses the fact that if bounded-Lipschitz distance is extended in the obvious way to signed measures then it fails to be a complete metric: http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219493712003584

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will think more about the dual version. A more direct approach is also welcome. 

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120291/metrization-of-weak-convergence-of-signed-measures

Answer (score 4):

(I guess you missed a square in your definition.)

2-Wasserstein distance doesn't respect the convex structure on measures. Consider two points $x_1 \ne x_2$ and Dirac measures $\delta(x_1), \delta(x_2)$. The measure $\frac{\delta(x_1)+\delta(x_2)}{2}$ is not a midpoint between $\delta(x_1)$ and $\delta(x_2)$.

Comment: You are right, I missed a square. I guess you are arguing why it can't be approximated by a norm? If I remember correctly, 2-Wasserstein is geodesically convex. So maybe it is possible to approximate it locally by a norm?

Answer (score 1):

This paper has several links to relevant literature by Kantorovich & Rubinstein who define an OT inspired norm for signed measures.

https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072186/en

Answer (score 0):

For the Earth-mover $W_1$ distance (based upon the cost function $c(x,y)=\|x-y\|$) this is exactly the purpose of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05105). Note however that their construction does **not** work for the quadratic cost $c(x,y)=\|x-y\|^2$ as you seem to be hoping for.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but I think the fact that the $W_1$ distance extends to a norm on the space of all signed measures with finite first moment is actually an immediate consequence of the classical Kantorovich-Rubinstein theorem: namely, this theorem shows that the $W_1$-distance is just a restriction of the (metric induced by the) norm on the dual space of the space of Lipschitz continuous functions that vanish at infinity. I guess the paper you linked is up to something more involved.