# Coupling of non-probability/sub-probability measures

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

A coupling of two probability measures $P,\tilde P$ on a Borel space $X$ is any probability measure on $X^2$ whose one-dimensional marginals are $P$ and $\tilde P$. In particular, for any such coupling $\Bbb P$ we have
$$
  2\cdot \Bbb P(X^2\setminus\Delta_X)\geq\|P - \tilde P\| \tag{1}
$$
where $\Delta_X = \{(x,x):x\in X\}$ is  the diagonal, and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the total variation norm. At the same time, there always exists a maximal coupling $\Bbb P^*$ such that the equality holds in $(1)$.

Extension of these results to the case when $P$ and $\tilde P$ are non-probability measures, or at least sub-probabilities does not seem to be complicated, however I wonder whether it has been already addressed somewhere. So far a search on google did not help.

Comment: Probably I've missed something: What do you mean by an extension of this result to non-probability measures? If $P$ and $\tilde P$ have the same total mass (but are not probabilities) anything is similar, but if the total mass is different, what should a coupling be?

Comment: @Dirk, it should, I think, be a measure $\mu$ on $X^2$ such that $\int_{y \in X} d\mu(x,y) = P(x)$ and $\int_{x \in X} d\mu(x,y) = \tilde{P}(y)$.

Comment: (hope my notation makes sense.) @Ilya, I don't know of any literature, but maybe the keyword "Wasserstein metric" helps (although the metric is defined for probability distributions). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric

Comment: The point is that if $P$ and $\tilde P$ have different mass there will be no coupling $\mu$: $\int_{x\in X}\int_{y\in X}d\mu(x,y) = \int_{x\in X}dP(x) \neq \int_{y\in X}d \tilde P(y) = \int_{y\in Y}\int_{x\in X}d\mu(x,y)$. For measures with different mass you may check this answer http://mathoverflow.net/a/120364/9652 which gives some hints (and a pointer to Gromov's  "Metric structures…" Chapter $3\tfrac12$).

Comment: @Dirk: thanks for the comment, but for the case when $P$ and $\tilde P$ have different total masses, can't we yet define $\mu:= P\otimes\tilde P$ to be at least one coupling?

Comment: @usul: to be honest, I am not sure how Wasserstein metric fits here: it crucially depends on the metric on the underlying space $X$ whereas maximal coupling is metric-free

Comment: @Ilya, not sure, but I thought there might exist relevant literature because it seems like an extreme case ... mainly, we can take the discrete metric ($\rho(x,y) = 1 \iff x \neq y$) and then Wasserstein distance should be $\mathbb{P}(X^2 \setminus \Delta_X)$ ...

Comment: @usul: you might be right, I'll check this out, though from what I remember a few things only hold for the Wasserstein metric on discrete uncountable spaces

Comment: @Ilya: $\mu = P\otimes \tilde P$ does not give the right masses for the marginals…

Comment: @Dirk: you're right, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought, I could turn the comments into an answer…

The approach by couplings does not work without modifications and the reason is that couplings do not exist if the measures have different total mass: If $P$ and $Q$ are two measures on $X$ with different total masses which were coupled by $\mu$, then
$$
\int_x\int_y d\mu(x,y) = \int_x dP(x) \neq \int_y d\tilde P(y) = \int_y\int_xd\mu(x,y).
$$ 
However, for a given metric $d$ for probability measures one can build a metric for measures with different masses as follows: If $P$ has total mass $P(X) = p$ and $Q$ has total mass $Q(X) = q$, define
$$
D(P,Q) = |p-q| + d(\tfrac{P}{p},\tfrac{Q}{q})
$$
(see Gromov's "Metric structures on Riemanian and Non-Riemannian Spaces", Chapter $3\tfrac12$.B).

There are also other approaches to metrics on measure spaces such as the Kantorovich-Rubinstein norm
$$
W(P,Q) = \sup\bigg\{\int f\, dP - \int f\, dQ\ :\ f\ \text{Lipschitz with constant}\ \leq 1\bigg\}
$$
and others (cf. Villani's "Optimal Transport - Old and New", Chapter 6).