# What is a metric for weak convergence of finite measures on a non compact, complete and separable metric space?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Consider the set of finite positive measures on a complete, separable, but not compact,  metric space $S$, endowed with the topology under which a sequence of finite positive measures $\{\mu_n\}$ converges to a finite positive measure $\mu$ if and only if $\int f d\mu_n \rightarrow \int f d\mu$ for every bounded continuous function $f$. If we restrict ourselves to the set of probability measures, i.e. measures $\mu$ such that $\mu(S)=1$, there is a metric (Prohorov's metric) that induces this topology.  Is there a metric that induces this topology on the set of all finite, positive measures?

Comment: What if you take 
$$|\mu-\nu|=\sup\left\{\,\left|\,\int\limits_S f\cdot(\mu-\nu)\,\right|\,\right\},$$
where the superemum is taken for all 1-Lipschitz function with supnorm at most 1?

Comment: You may assume that the metric is bounded above by $1$ define a Kantorovich (- Rubinshtein (or Wasserstein) metric like in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120291/metrization-of-weak-convergence-of-signed-measures